# Proper Usage of `noexcept`

Tags: c++, noexcept

I'm trying to figure out the proper way of using the `noexcept` attribute. I've already spent half a day trying to understand it, but I'm not sure I did. And I don't want to use or not to use `noexcept` everywhere mindlessly.

**Question:** Do I understand it right, that if a function calls **only** functions that **have** `noexcept` attribute, then we may (or should) safely mark our function as `noexcept` too?

---

Suppose, I have functions that check whether a provided path exists and is a directory. I use `filesystem` for that purpose. One function (`IsDir`) calls [`exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) and [`is_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_directory) functions that are **not** marked as `noexcept`. The other function (`IsDir2`) calls [`exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) and [`is_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_directory) functions that **are** marked as `noexcept`. Can I safely mark the second function as `noexcept`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

bool IsDir(const fs::path& p) {
  const bool exists{ fs::exists(p) };        // Not marked as "noexcept".
  const bool is_dir{ fs::is_directory(p) };  // Not marked as "noexcept".
  return exists && is_dir;
}

bool IsDir2(const fs::path& p, std::error_code& ec) noexcept {
  const bool exists{ fs::exists(p, ec) };        // "noexcept" version.
  const bool is_dir{ fs::is_directory(p, ec) };  // "noexcept" version.
  return exists && is_dir;
}

int main () {
  const fs::path p("~/Some_Path");
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsDir(p) << std::endl;

  std::error_code ec;
  std::cout << IsDir2(p, ec) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not answering your *specific* question but there's another issue with your `IsDir2` function. It it generates an error code for `exists` but not for `is_directory`, you'll end up losing that first error code because `ec` will be overwritten. Probably better would be something like `if (! fs::exists(p, ec)) return false; return fs::is_directory(p, ec);`

Comment: @paxdiablo, thank you for your comment! I didn't notice that possible error.

Comment: @JeJo, I saw that question, but I'm not sure I understood it correctly.

Comment: Also, it's *probably* a safe bet that, if the file doesn't exists, it won't be considered a directory (should confirm this though). Doing both checks runs the risk of a race condition if the directory is actually created between the two checks.

Comment: @paxdiablo, good catch! Thank you once again!

Comment: Note that not only functions must not throw any exceptions, but also every operator, implicit conversion, ect.. E.g. changing the type of `p` to `char const*` would get you into trouble, since constructing a `std::filesystem::path` object could throw an exception. As an alternative you could of course catch those exceptions that may be happening in the function. There may be scenarios where you want `std::terminate` to be called, if any operation throws an exception, so you may mark a function as `noexcept` for this reason.

Comment: Note: There are a few functions that because of compatibility reasons with the C standard library functions not properly marked as `noexcept`, e.g. `std::strlen`. You should be able to use those inside of a `noexcept` function without any issues. (You'd still need to make sure the preconditions for calling the function are met, e.g. the string passed must be terminated by `'\0'`.)

Comment: @fabian, thank you for such a detailed comment! If you post it as the answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, it is very easy to get `noexcept` tagging wrong.  It needs to be done with careful scrutiny.  One dev I know put `noexcept` everywhere, and was not happy when I pointed out that almost every place he added that tag could potentially throw.  Which I suppose is okay if the program's policy is "a `throw` means to terminate the application".

Comment: @Eljay, it looks like some programmers don't use it at all and others use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 scenarios when you'd want to mark a function:

- To tell the compiler no exception can be thrown from the function
- To tell the compiler to call `std::terminate`, if a function would otherwise "escape" the function.

If only the former is the desired effect, there are several things that you need to take into consideration:

- There is logic other than functions that could result in exceptions being thrown. Examples are: Calls to operators, conversions(implicit or expicit), constructor calls, ... . Mandatory copy elision can complicate the analysis.
- Third party functions are not maked `noexcept` in all scenarios. Some libraries are pre-C++11 compatible and the keyword wasn't even available. Some libraries didn't want to risk ABI breaks or didn't consider it worth the effort adding the keyword in. Some libraries need to be compatible with C, where the keyword isn't available; this includes functions in the C++ standard library such as `std::strlen`. In some cases where templates are involved, the required conditional `noexcept` specification could get too complicated for the implementor to bother.

In your `IsDir2` your analysis regarding no exception being thrown inside the function body, so marking it as `noexcept` is appropriate, but as noted by @paxdiablo in the comments the implementation of the function may require an overhaul.

Answer (score 1):

Functions marked as `noexcept` behave mostly as

```
void Function(/*...*/) /* noexcept */
{
   try {
      // ...
   } catch (...) {
       std::terminate();
   }
}
```

> Question: Do I understand it right, that if a function calls only functions that have `noexcept` attribute, then we may (or should) safely mark our function as `noexcept` too?

You miss some cases:

- You might `throw` yourself, even if only `noexcept` functions are called.
- you might catch exception of throwing exception yourself, so your function can promise to not throw

`noexcept` is part of the interface or your function, so do you want that restriction of not (changing interface might be harder/problematic with retro-compatibility)...

> And I don't want to use or not to use `noexcept` everywhere mindlessly.

`noexcept` might allow some (micro) optimisations compiler side.

Library side, marking move constructor as `noexcept` allows `std::vector` to use move constructor instead of copy constructor in some scenario.

Comment: Jarod42, thank you for the explanation! Especially for the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Lakos Rule - Only functions with *wide contracts* must be `noexcept`

The only case in which it is safe to use `noexcept` is when there's absolutely no way your function will ever throw, even in the future, when the implementation is changed. Your function must have a *wide contract*, i.e. it has no preconditions at all, and produces a valid result for *any* possible inputs and global state.

If you mark your function `noexcept` and it does `throw`, `std::terminate` will be called and your program aborts ungracefully. This makes little sense, and it would be better to handle thrown exceptions somewhere at the call site. If need be, put a `try ... catch` block around all of `main`. Calling `std::terminate` prevents any sane error handling and should be avoided.

*See also: [Arthur O' Dwyer - The Lakos Rule](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/04/25/the-lakos-rule/).*

#### Is it okay to break Lakos' Rule?

Yes, the rule is meant for standard library design, and you don't have to be as strict. However, if you put `noexcept` on a function with a narrow contract, you have to be absolutely sure this will never change, and you will never throw. The code which uses this function may rely on your function being `noexcept`, and removing `noexcept` later might break it.

**Only put `noexcept` on functions with narrow contracts when you're sure that they will stay `noexcept` forever.**

For example, [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) is `noexcept` in some standard libraries because it's a function from C, so it makes no sense for it to throw. However, this is not guaranteed by the C++ standard, because it has a narrow contract (it would break when given a `nullptr`).

#### Q & A

> Do I understand it right, that if a function calls only functions that have `noexcept` attribute, then we may (or should) safely mark our function as `noexcept` too?

It is still possible that our function throws, or might throw in the future. For example:

```cpp
int div(int x, int y) { // don't make this noexcept, narrow contract
    return x / y; // possible division by zero
}
```

This function calls no other functions, and it doesn't throw anything, so at first sight, it should be `noexcept`. However, it has a narrow contract because it is not well-defined for `y == 0`. Even if it doesn't throw exception now, you might change your mind in the future and `throw std::invalid_argument`.

> ```cpp
> bool IsDir2(const fs::path& p, std::error_code& ec) noexcept {
>  const bool exists{ fs::exists(p, ec) };        // "noexcept" version.
>  const bool is_dir{ fs::is_directory(p, ec) };  // "noexcept" version.
>  return exists && is_dir;
> }
> ```
>
> [`IsDir2`] calls `exists` and `is_directory` functions that are marked as `noexcept`. Can I safely mark the second function as `noexcept`?

Yes, but not because it only calls `noexcept` functions. You mark it `noexcept` becaues it has a *wide contract*. If anything fails inside the function, it should communicate that by writing to `ec`. It would make no sense for it to *also* throw exceptions, no matter how you implement it.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! It does make sense, though, I guess I won't use the `noexcept`.